# How to define the mapDispatchToProps type of redux thunk function

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux

Follow the [official doc](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#usage-with-redux-thunk), I make a login typescript like thunk function.

```
function loginApi(user: UserState) {
  return fetch(
    `${baseUrl}/login?user=${user.userName}&pwd=${user.pwd}`
  )
    .then(res => res.json())
}

export const thunkLogin = (
  user: UserState
): ThunkAction<void, AppState, null, Action<string>> => async dispatch => {
  const asyncResp = await loginApi(user)
  dispatch(
    updateUser({
      loggedIn: asyncResp.isloggedIn,
      userName: user.userName,
      userPwd: user.userPwd
    })
  )
}
```

I want add this thunk function to my app component using react-redux connect hoc function.

```
import { thunkLogin } from './thunkLoginPath'

interface Props {
  // place 1
  thunkLogin: typeof thunkLogin
}

interface State {
  userName: string
  userPwd: string
}

class AppComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.thunkLogin({
      userName: this.state.userName,
      userPwd: this.state.userPwd
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={style.loginBotton}
        onPress={this.handleSubmit}
      >
        <Text style={style.loginBottomText}>LOGIN</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state: AppState) => ({
    user: state.user
  }),
  // place 2
  { thunkLogin }
)(AppComponent)
```

It report a error show that the thunkLogin declare at Props not assignable to mapDispatchToProps (place 1 -> place 2).

Answer (score 0):

did you mean to connect AppComponent or Login component, since you trying
to call this.props.thunkLogin from AppComponent but you connect Login.
try to change it like this.

```
export default connect(
  (state: AppState) => ({
    user: state.user
  }),
  // place 2
  { thunkLogin }
)(AppComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mapDispatchToProps` is totally okay. If you want to use some other syntax here you have:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    thunkLogin: (user: UserState) => {
      dispatch(thunkLogin(user))
    }
  }
}
```

But I think that this won't help you with TypeScript errors. At least I had many many problems with react-thunk. I ended up throwing away all that `ThunkAction` crap since TypeScript is smart enough to recognize functions types. I only took care that nested function of action creator returns `any`. In reality it always returns `void` (but TypeScript doesn't like it). Your function would look something like this:

```
export const thunkLogin = (user: UserState) => async (dispatch): any => {
  const asyncResp = await loginApi(user)
  dispatch(
    updateUser({
      loggedIn: asyncResp.isloggedIn,
      userName: user.userName,
      userPwd: user.userPwd
    })
  )
}
```

This solution is good enough for me, because it shows me typing inside the component. I can be aware if action creator is regular or thunk-powered. An example:
[image: mapDispatchToProps example]

If you want to read more about react-thunk and typescript, go here:
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/103